# Change DataGrid Column Headers in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a DataGrid as shown below

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="0,5,10,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Products, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="productName" Binding="{Binding Path Name}" Header="Name To Change">
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

For the code I'm using the DataContextSpy

```
    public class DataContextSpy : Freezable
{
    public DataContextSpy()
    {
        // This binding allows the spy to inherit a DataContext.
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, DataContextProperty, new Binding());
    }

    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return GetValue(DataContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataContextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Borrow the DataContext dependency property from FrameworkElement.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextProperty = FrameworkElement
        .DataContextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DataContextSpy));

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        // We are required to override this abstract method.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then I have the MVVM Viewmodel with the property which i want to bind the header to like this:

```
    public class ViewModel: ViewModelBase{
    string header1;
    Public string Header1{
    get{return header1;}
    set{
    Set(ref header1, value);
    }
    ...........
    My question is why is it not binding to the property? Anny suggestions?
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Header1` is defined in the same view model class as the `Products` property, you could use a `HeaderTemplate` like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="productName" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Header1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I'll mark this as answer but how can I implement property changes. I'd Like the columns to change at runtime?

Comment: That should just be a matter of setting the Header1 source property to a new value and raise the PropertyChanged event. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.